# "Permission denied" when trying to handle a "Share Image" intent from Browser in my own activity

Tags: android, permissions, android-intent

I'm trying to write a simple activity which does the following:
A user holds down on an image viewed in the Android Browser and then presses "Share image" and chooses my Activity to handle it. I want to be able to open the image file from within my activity.

The file path ends up being: /data/data/com.android.browser/app_sharedimage/SOME_FILE_NAME.jpg
and calling "File()" on the path results in a permission error:
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/data/com.android.browser/app_sharedimage/SOME_FILE_NAME.jpg (Permission denied")

How can I open this image file? Is there some permission I need to put in the manifest?

Here's the relevant code:

```
        if (Intent.ACTION_SEND.equals(intent.getAction())) {
            if (extras.containsKey(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM)) {
                Uri uri = (Uri) extras.getParcelable(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM);

                String scheme = uri.getScheme();
                if (scheme.equals("content")) {
                    String mimeType = intent.getType();
                    ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();
                    Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(uri, null, null,
                            null, null);
                    cursor.moveToFirst();
                    String filePath = cursor.getString(cursor
                            .getColumnIndexOrThrow(Images.Media.DATA));
                    ...
                    ...
                    new FileBody(new File(filePath)) 
                    ...
```

Comment: Is this shared_image location is your app private folder (or) android root folder (which is not created by your app)?

Comment: it's an android root folder presumably only accessible by the Android Browser app

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK you wont be able to access private files of any other applications unless your phone is rooted. So I think you wont be able open the image.

Comment: How do other apps handle the "Share Image" intent? For example, the Twitter app can take a "Share Image" intent and upload the image to a server.

Comment: So on your phone you are able to share image from browser onto twitter? My nexus S cannot do this. Offcourse apps which store images onto sdcard can do this.

Comment: Yes I'm able to share image from browser to Twitter, facebook, and all apps in the "Share via" menu, except for my app. Very strange. Does the browser also send the actual internet url of the image in the intent? I checked the intent.getExtras() bundle and there's only EXTRA_STREAM

Comment: did you check intent.getdata , may be the public uri is present in this.

Comment: just checked, unfortunately it's not

Answer (score 0):

I can display (I suppose this is what you mean by opening) an image from the browser on a HTC Desire and it is not rooted.

I use the URI just like you from the extras in the Intent. Then I get an InputStream and create a Drawable from it, which can be displayed in an ImageView.

The URI I get is:

> content://htcbrowser/share_image/data/data/com.android.browser/app_sharedimage/logo3w.png?image/png

```
if (intent.getType() != null && intent.getType().indexOf("image/") != -1) {
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
         if (extras.containsKey(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM)) {
            Uri uri = (Uri) extras.getParcelable(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM);
            ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
            try {
                InputStream is = getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
                Drawable myDrawable = Drawable.createFromStream(is, "srcName");
                iv.setImageDrawable(myDrawable);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Once you have an InputStream you can create a File from it if your app needs that.